# How to set event agrument converter in event trigger in Prism?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism, eventtrigger

I use Prism in my project and I want to have a converter in the event trigger to convert the event argument to my class model.

The problem is that the converter is not called in the Prism implementation and sends the event arguments directly to the view model.

This is my XAML code:

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
    <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="RecordExpanding">
        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RowExpandCommand}" 
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=events:RecordExpandingEventArgs}, Converter={StaticResource DataGridRecordExpandingConverter}}" />
    </interactivity:EventTrigger>
</interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: So what is your question? What have you tried? What does not work?

Comment: It didn't work and did not check converter and it directly jump to viewModel

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use event arguments in viewModel, then I use a converter to convert event arguments to a model.

Comment: What's wrong with mvvm light's `EventToCommand`? Just copy the one file into your project and you're good to go, MIT license should be fine.

Comment: i use prism in my project and i can`t use MVVMLight

Comment: If `InvokeCommandAction` doesn't provide what you need, you're allowed to look elsewhere :-) You've tried `TriggerParameterPath="Record.Cells[0].Value"`, have you?

Comment: `i can't use MVVMLight` does mean what exactly? I wasn't suggesting to dump Prism, I suggested you borrow _a single class_ from mvvm light and add it to your code base.

Comment: yes, i tried to get "Record.Cells[0].Value" in a converter an fill a class model to pass to viewModel

Comment: @RezaHosseini I'm not talking about a converter, I'm talking about `InvokeCommandAction.TriggerParameterPath`.

Comment: @RezaHosseini, Can you show me what package you are using. I am event cant use prism.InvokeCommandAction with xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors". thanks

Answer (score 0):

It does not work, because your assumptions about the parameter binding are wrong. The Prism `InvokeCommandAction` automatically assigns the event arguments of the associated event as command parameter, if you do not specify a parameter yourself. In the latter case it is overwritten.

Your parameter binding uses a `RelativeSource`. This is only suitable, if you want to bind to properties of an ancestor of your control in the logical tree or the control itself. This does **not work** with events, because they are not part of the tree.

However, there is a solution to your problem. You can specify which property of your event arguments will be passed as command parameter using the `TriggerParameterPath` property. Let us assume that your `RecordExpandingEventArgs` have a property called `Record` that you want to pass, then your action looks like this:

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
    <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="RecordExpanding">
        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RowExpandCommand}" 
                                   TriggerParameterPath="Record"/>
    </interactivity:EventTrigger>
</interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Note that this also works for nested properties like `Record.Cells`. Alternatively, you can also use `EventToCommand` from MVVM Light framework, where you can explicitly specify an event arguments converter.